# Plotting a piecewise continuous function

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to plot a piecewise function that is not continuous using the following code. However, the output always appears a continuous function, as MATLAB joins the gaps between these sub-functions.

```
i1 = -2:0;
i2 = 0:pi/2;
i3 = pi/2:pi;
f1 = sinh(i1)+2;
f2 = sin(i2)-2;
f3= 2*i3.^2-2*pi*i3+3;
plot([i1 i2 i3],[f1,f2,f3]);
```

How should I resolve this problem in a not-so-complicated way?

PS. I am using MATLAB 2013a, it seems that the function [`piecewise`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/piecewise.html) doesn't exist in this version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `nan` between the functions, that'll disjoin them:

```
i1 = -2:0;
i2 = 0:pi/2;
i3 = pi/2:pi;
f1 = sinh(i1)+2;
f2 = sin(i2)-2;
f3= 2*i3.^2-2*pi*i3+3;
plot([i1 nan i2 nan i3],[f1,nan,f2,nan,f3]);
```

[image]

The other option, resulting in the same graph, is to plot all three of them separately using `hold on`:

```
figure;
hold on
plot(i1,f1,'b');
plot(i2,f2,'b');
plot(i3,f3,'b');
```

Or use the `plot(X,Y,X1,Y1,...,Xn,Yn` syntax:

```
figure;
plot(i1,f1,'b',i2,f2,'b',i3,f3,'b')
```

Note that for the latter two you must specify the line style, so as to prevent MATLAB from making them separate colours, hence the `'b'`.

Comment: Thank Adriaan. If I now plot the following continuous function:  i1 = -2:0;
i2 = 0:pi/2;
i3 = pi/2:pi;
f1 = sinh(i1);
f2 = sin(i2);
f3= 4*i3.^2-2*pi*i3+1;
plot([i1 nan i2 nan i3],[f1,nan,f2,nan,f3]); It appears to be not continuous. How do I fix it?

Comment: @Hahn don't put the nan's there, obviously. Or use one of the other versions mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but normally we don't know whether the function is continuous or not. The other versions encounter the same problem.

Comment: @Hahn So you use one of the other two options I mentioned. Those will keep joined lines perfectly joined, and disjoint lines perfectly disjoint. It reads like you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), since writing your functions separate like this is probably not the best solution. Asking about the problem, not your proposed solution might yield better results.